# How to alter the date format of date column without changing the column data type using polars dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, date, datetime, python-polars

How to alter the date format of date column without changing the column data type using polars dataframe.

I have dataframe as below
[image]

I wanted to convert the first column (i.e Date) to %d-%b-%y format without changing its data type to string. How do I do that?

Comment: this is just how polars displays dates / datetimes. if you want to display it in a different way, you'll need to do `.dt.strftime`, but then it'll be stored as utf8

Comment: @ignoring_gravity You wouldn't have to *store* them as utf8. You could "just" do `.with_columns(pl.col(pl.Date,pl.Datetime).dt.strftime("%d-%b-%y"))` at the end of whatever you want to print.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a good direct way to do this right now. You could manually, or via monkey patching `__str__`, do `.with_columns(pl.col(pl.Date,pl.Datetime).dt.strftime("%d-%b-%y")` at the end of whatever you want to print.

To monkey patch it you would do

```
def newstr(self):
    return (
    df
    .with_columns(pl.col(pl.Date,pl.Datetime).dt.strftime("%d-%b-%y"))
    ._df.as_str()
)
pl.DataFrame.__str__ = newstr
```

then if you have

```
df=pl.select(pl.datetime_range(pl.datetime(2023,12,x+1,1), pl.datetime(2023,12,x+1,1)+pl.duration(days=5),'1d').alias(f'a{x}')
          for x in range(5)
          )
```

you can then do:

```
print(df)
shape: (6, 5)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ a0        ┆ a1        ┆ a2        ┆ a3        ┆ a4        │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ str       ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ str       ┆ str       │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 01-Dec-23 ┆ 02-Dec-23 ┆ 03-Dec-23 ┆ 04-Dec-23 ┆ 05-Dec-23 │
│ 02-Dec-23 ┆ 03-Dec-23 ┆ 04-Dec-23 ┆ 05-Dec-23 ┆ 06-Dec-23 │
│ 03-Dec-23 ┆ 04-Dec-23 ┆ 05-Dec-23 ┆ 06-Dec-23 ┆ 07-Dec-23 │
│ 04-Dec-23 ┆ 05-Dec-23 ┆ 06-Dec-23 ┆ 07-Dec-23 ┆ 08-Dec-23 │
│ 05-Dec-23 ┆ 06-Dec-23 ┆ 07-Dec-23 ┆ 08-Dec-23 ┆ 09-Dec-23 │
│ 06-Dec-23 ┆ 07-Dec-23 ┆ 08-Dec-23 ┆ 09-Dec-23 ┆ 10-Dec-23 │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

With this approach you don't know the datatypes of the columns and if it's a really big df then it'll convert all the dates to string (not just the ones being displayed) so it could produce a lag for the output to pop up.

You could make your new `__str__` method more complex to handle those cases if you really wanted to.